# basic SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I just started to learn SQL and I have some queries to write to practise.

Can you help me and check it if it's correct?

I don't have an idea how to create three at the end

Let's assume that database is arbitrary. I just need to learn how to create those kind of queries to work on many diffrent databases.

**-Specify the time from the system clock and the system clock date.**

```
SELECT SYSDATETIME(),SYSDATETIMEOFFSET();
```

**-Select employees that are in the age from 30 to 50 years.**

```
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE dateOfBirth BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 YEAR) 
                  AND DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 50 YEAR);
```

**-Indicate in which department the employee works.**

```
select employees.name, departments.name from employees where
employees.id_department=departments.id_department;
```

**-Specify in what department the employee works and order in descending order and ascending order by name**

```
select employees.name, departments.name from employees where
employees.id_department=departments.id_department ORDER BY Department DESC, Surname ASC;
```

**-Specify in which department the employee works and order in descending order and ascending order by name limiting the number of tuples to chapters beginning with a or s.**

**-Is there a business department where no one is working?**

**View your net worker's salary, calculate your 18% tax rate and give you a tax deduction.**

Comment: Hard to check if you don't include the definition of the tables being used in the exercise. :)

Comment: I don't have database that I used on my course but still I have to write those queries so let's assume that any column naming that you want is allowed

Comment: If You work with time types, there are a lot of database specific stuff.

Comment: Too broad (asking multiple questions) with little context (No info about table structure or data). And blatantly just trying to get answers for a course project/test

Comment: @Jason Joslin If you'd read my whole question and comments you might noticed that I wrote that I don't have table structure. And yes, congrats, I'm trying to CHECK if I'm right (I wrote some queries - not all cause I can't) not just wait for your answers. I was just lookin for some help, If it's not okay with you, just skip the post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this also. Would assume something like below:

```
select employees.name, departments.name from departments 
Left Outer Join departments on departments.id_department = employees.id_department 
WHERE employees.name IS NULL
```